# Construct matrix by diagonals from vector

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Given v={v1,v2,v3,v4} 
how can i construct the matrix

```
 M={{ v1, v2, v3, v4, -v3, -v2},
    { v2, v1, v2, v3,  v4, -v3},
    { v3, v2, v1, v2,  v3,  v4},
    { v4, v3, v2, v1,  v2,  v3},
    {-v3, v4, v3, v2,  v1,  v2},
    {-v2,-v3, v4, v3,  v2,  v1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `ToeplitzMatrix` can be useful for this case:

```
 ToeplitzMatrix[{v1, v2, v3, v4, -v3, -v2}]
```

> ```
> {{ v1,  v2, v3, v4, -v3, -v2}, 
>  { v2,  v1, v2, v3,  v4, -v3}, 
>  { v3,  v2, v1, v2,  v3,  v4}, 
>  { v4,  v3, v2, v1,  v2,  v3}, 
>  {-v3,  v4, v3, v2,  v1,  v2}, 
>  {-v2, -v3, v4, v3,  v2,  v1}}
> ```

There is also an undocumented option `"ReflectedNegation"` for `ArrayPad` which can help to generate the reflected input array i.e.:

```
v = {v1, v2, v3, v4};
ArrayPad[v, {0, 2}, "ReflectedNegation"]
```

> ```
> {v1, v2, v3, v4, -v3, -v2}
> ```

Thus, the full command will be:

```
ToeplitzMatrix[ArrayPad[v, {0, 2}, "ReflectedNegation"]]
```